# VSIX extension to select class

Tags: c#, roslyn, vsix

I want to develop an extension for Visual Studio 2017 which will allow user to right click on C# class and choose to invoke wizard from the context menu. I see here that it is possible with VSIX template. I also looked into Roslyn and feels that it might be the way to go forward but not sure. Basically I wan to select the class and read all it's properties hierarchically to show it in tree view and let user decide select from those. The point I am stuck at is if it is possible in Roslyn and can I use C# reflection there as well.

Thanks
Jay

Comment: What do you mean by "select the class"?